# Data Sorting in Memory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

I have 5 million record and each record are unique. I want to sort these 5 million record in memory. Is there any way to do.  In python and R we will get memory issue. In Hadoop Spark is it possible to do in memory itself.

Comment: You can use `sc.sortByKey()` to achieve this.

Comment: thanks Avihoo, we can use sc.sortByKey(). But my data is distributed in my cluster.

Comment: That's the whole purpose of Spark. Parallelizing your data between all the workers, and each worker is doing a small job, and then do something with the collected results. The framework allows you to use sortByKey because the shuffle sort will be done by the framework and each worker will do it own job.